# Cannot render with Nvidia GPU

Tags: rendering, gpu, compile

I am trying to render a model with the Cycles render on my GPU (GTX 1650) but the rendering fails. I am using Blender 2.79 and I have Nvidia driver 418.56 version. I am also using Ubuntu.

This is what I get from the console:

> `CUDA version 10.0 detected, build may succeed but only CUDA 8.0 is
>   officially supported. Compiling CUDA kernel ...
>   "/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc" -arch=sm_75 --cubin
>   "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/source/kernel/kernels/cuda/kernel.cu"
>   -o "/home/<USER>/.cache/cycles/kernels/cycles_kernel_sm75_78F3CD3A6B833245ABFC15B6E5CDBEE8.cubin"
>   -m64 --ptxas-options="-v" --use_fast_math -DNVCC -D__KERNEL_CUDA_VERSION__=101 -I"/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/source"  <built-in>: fatal error: when writing output to : Bad file descriptor compilation
>   terminated. CUDA kernel compilation failed, see console for details.`

I tried compiling `kernel.cu` file with nvcc, and this is what I get:

> `kernel.cu:21:10: fatal error: kernel/kernel_compat_cuda.h: No such
>   file or directory  #include "kernel/kernel_compat_cuda.h"
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.`

The `kernel.cu` file is in `/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/source/kernel/kernels/cuda`.

At a first glance, it seems that the problem can be fixed by replacing the `#include` with the following: `#include "../../../kernel/kernel_compat_cuda.h"`.

But that'd require a lot of changes in the source code of each file. Is there any easier way to fix it?

Comment: try to download a newest build of blender, GTX 1650 is a quite new device

Comment: @Hikariztw yes, I just used Blender 2.8 beta and now it renders the model with the GPU. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use 2.79 in nightly build either, https://builder.blender.org/download/